# Controller inheritance in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot application with many different @RestController
all of them in the beginning do the following:

```
if (user != null) {
            log.debug("Got the following request: " + request.getURI().getPath() + " from: " + user.getName());
        } else {
            log.error("Warning user is not defined");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }
```

How can i make a parent controller that for all the requests will do these checks and than each child controller will continue with its unique logic?

Comment: If you want to make sure that the user making the request is authenticated you should use `Spring Security`.

Comment: Thanks im using spring security, in this context i just want to print the user name making the request

Comment: That sounds like a job for `Spring AOP`. Create a handler and point the `@Before` method at your controller package.

Comment: Or like Filter or Interceptor. But base class should also work. Maybe you can post one of your controllers and explain why the simple base/sub-class approaches aren't working?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned in the comments, there is lots of ways to get this working. Personally, I would prefer Spring AOP to log these stuff or an interceptor/filter. However, none the less you can get this working with inheritance itself per se it is not a good solution. Doing somewhat similar example and hoping you can pick from there.

```
public class A extends Logger {
    //RequestMapping stuff
    public void test(){
        logInfo(user);
    }
}

public class Logger {
    public void logInfo(User user){
        // Your log statements here
    }
}
```

This not only makes it pointless but also unscalable as you have to do lot of `find and replace` and minor changes to the controller or the log statements will be tedious as your application grows.